# Cloudfront with s3 doesn't update the page right away with new deployment [enforce https for react app]

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, https, amazon-cloudfront

I am using S3 for react website and started using cloudfront primarily to easily redirect Http traffic to Https. I don't cache anything, and cloudfront has 0 for the min, default and max age. However, when I deploy new versions to s3, the page for user is not updates unless he reloads the page the second time.

Is there a way to make sure it's available for user right away without having him reload the page one more time (and without manually invalidating cloudfront)? Or maybe there is an easy way to force https for something like that?

Thank you!

Comment: That sounds like the *browser* cache.  Are you sending appropriate `Cache-Control` headers to prevent that (assuming for some reason that it is what you actually want)?

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like a cloudfront issue since the TTL for your resources is set to 0. Hence the content is served directly from your origin.

However, the need to reload the page comes from your browser cache i believe. This does not involve cloudfront for sure.